# How to run nightshade scripts on local machine

Tags: astronomy

Alright, so Nightshade NG with StratoScript is a way to program scripts for a specific digital Planetarium. This is a topic that few of you will know about, and I've got a question on the programming software itself, so if you had no idea what Nightshade NG or what StratoScript was when you clicked this link, you probably can't help me, so feel free to move on.

I know this Nightshade NG is a unique and relatively new software, and because of that fact, Nightshade's own forum is rarely answered. This question is on StackOverflow to see if the *stars align* (get it? it's a pun ahaha) for someone with this unique knowledge to see this question, as I don't think anyone will be answering my post on the nightshade website anytime soon.

My Nightshade website post is here:
http://www.nightshadesoftware.org/boards/2/topics/152

The question is:
I’d like to work on scripts while at home and away from the planetarium. I have installed Nightshade NG, and it opens alright, and I’ve found the script folder in its program files. But how do I run it for testing purposes on desktop? On the old version, I just named it startup.sts and it worked when I booted up nightshade, but that doesn’t work for this one. I just need to be able to run a script, I don’t care what I have to name the script, I just need to test scripts here so I will have them ready to test on the real thing.

**Again, I'd like to point out that I know it's unlikely anyone here can help me. But I have looked all over the internet and cannot find an answer anywhere. I've got nothing to lose by checking to see if any of my mates on stackoverflow have an answer!**

Comment: what are you asking has nothing to do with astronomy itself you should rethink your tags otherwise not the right people will click on your question hence no valid answers ... Also I would change the title a bit  (although I have no clue what the Nightshade is) to something like: **How to run/configure nightshade scripts on local machine**

Comment: Ok I'll change change title. I couldn't do any different tags because I don't use this sit enough to have reputation. It said I couldn't use the tags Nightshade or StratoScript or NightshadeNG so I didn't know what to do to tag it

Comment: Seems that is because they do not exist and you have too low rep to create one ...  as they do not exist yet then it indicates no one uses it as much to ask any questions about it yet so I doubt anyone here would be able to help.

Comment: btw as you are building planetarium may be this QA might interest you: [Is it possible to make realistic n-body solar system simulation in matter of size and mass?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214)

Comment: Thanks, although the Planetarium's already up and running. I can do a show from the control panel, and I can run scripts on the Planetarium. The only thing left to do is create scripts for someone else to run so they don't need me at the control panel to do a show. I know how to make scripts, it would just be easier if I could get Nightshade working on a desktop computer so I could test the scripts at home. But thanks for the link, I'll check it out and see if anything interesting is in there!

Answer (score 0):

Name the script XX-scriptname.sts where XX is a two digit number (I assume other lengths work as well but have only tried 2).
While in Nightshade, type 'y'+'XX' to run that script. For example, if you wanted to create a script to see a lunar eclipse, you could call it '01-lunareclipse.sts'. Then when you want to run it type 'y01'. 
There's no window that pops up to let you type into, it's all read in the background. Also, don't type too slowly. If you wait after hitting 'y' it'll time out and whatever number you hit next might trigger a different action.